# I'm making a multi-layer stencil. How can I keep the threshold of each layer live?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: layer structure and hue]

I am trying to make a multi-layer stencil effect in PS CS6.

How I got here:
1. Made several copies of original image
2. Image> Adjustments> Threshold, for each one at different levels.
3. Select > Colour Range > Highlights + delete. Gets rid of the white, leaving just the blackness of the threshold effect.
4. Make adjustment layer for to change the Hue/Saturation. Giving me different grays.

However, Ideally I would like to be able to change threshold levels, as a live effect, so I can see how the layers stack. Cannot quite figure out whether this is possible or not.

Once I remove the white, there's no turning back.

Any ideas how I could use the threshold effect with on a transparent background?

I appreciate your time!

**TL;DR: How could I use the threshold function as *black/transparent* not *black/white*.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Threshold *adjustment layers* they same way you've used Hue/Saturation adjustment layers rather than applying threshold directly to layers.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am aware of this, but still doesnt allow me to play with the thresholds while staking layers. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. Adjustment layers allow for non-destructive editing at any time. No clue what *"play with threshold while stacking layers"* means.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is the following:

Basically for each layer of the stencil, I first convert layer to Smart Object, and then:

1. I add the Threshold Adjustment Layer - making sure the "Clip to Layer" icon is checked. This can be changed, since it's a live adjustment.
2. I double-click the layer: Layer style > Blending options >Blend if > Adjusting the grey slider until the white of the Threshold effect disappears, leaving only the black. (holding ALT while clicking the slider, allows a range to be set, this allowing a threshold level range to be chosen)
3. Then I add a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer to change the black it into any grey/colour I want.

[THANKS "AwwwSnack"!](https://www.reddit.com/user/AwwwSnack)

[image: Visual description of the solution - Each stencil layer has its own group]

Comment: This also works without converting to a Live Layer (at least on CC). Just clip the adjustment layer to your copy of the image layer and set blending options of that image layer as you indicated.